# How to make an array from a SELECT returning more than one row

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate

Is it possible to make one big array from a query like:

```
select
array_append(ARRAY[0], console_id)
from archive_sessions
where tournament_id = 14817
```

I tried with `group by` but I have to use console_id in it and it still is more than 1 row.

And how in this query initializing an empty `ARRAY[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select array_agg(console_id) as consoles from archive_sessions where tournament_id = 14817
```

Comment: I have seen this function but why I didnt try it -1 for me +1 for you

Answer (score 4):

If the query only returns column(s) that go into the array, use an [ARRAY constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT console_id FROM archive_sessions
             WHERE  tournament_id = 14817) AS console_arr;
```

This is typically *faster* than `array_agg()` for the simple case.