# Use SQL query as array parameter (input) in custom function

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I created a custom function in pl/pgsql and it's only input is an array. I would like to use the result of a query as the input for this custom function, but can't seem to get it right. I'll use a simpler function as an example and also a simpler query than the one I'm trying to use as input.

Function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigger_than_ones(input_array int[])
returns SETOF int
AS
$$
DECLARE
  array_item int;
BEGIN
  FOREACH array_item in ARRAY input_array
  LOOP
    IF array_item > 1 THEN
      RETURN NEXT array_item;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have a table that has a column the same datatype of the array datatype. In this case an integer column:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
id | int_attribute
---+--------------
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 1
4  | 4
5  | 1
6  | 6
7  | 1
8  | 1
9  | 8
```

I would like to use a query that returns a column of that datatype as the input for my function. I've tried a few variations of this, without any luck:

```
SELECT * FROM bigger_than_ones(SELECT int_attribute FROM my_table);
```

To return:

```
result 
-------------
2
3
4
6
8
```

The reason I'm using a similarly structured function is because I need to calculate resulting merged time ranges (custom type) from multiple tables, in multiple places in my code. My best thought was to create a function that would do that, using as input all the time ranges, regardless of where I took it from, so I wouldn't have to make a more complex query each time.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve with the query. Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: isn't that simply `select int_attribute from my_table where int_attribute > 1`?

Comment: your function expects an **array**. Why do you think you can (or should) pass it a simple integer value? Why did you define your function like that?

Comment: I know the function in the example is not very useful as is, and would be easily replaced with a simple query. I simplified the original function to make it readable in SO context.

Comment: You simplified the question to an extent where it doesn't make sense any longer

Comment: The question was "I created a custom function in pl/pgsql and it's only input is an array. I would like to use the result of a query as the input for this custom function". You focused on the usefulness of the custom function. I think I found the answer, I'll post as soon as I test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you found is an [**ARRAY constructor**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS), which is *not* an operator (nor a function), but an SQL construct (an SQL syntax element). The referenced answer used the wrong term (now fixed). The difference might matter.

```
SELECT * FROM bigger_than_ones(ARRAY(SELECT int_attribute FROM my_table));
```

You could also use the basic [aggregate function `array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), which is easier to integrate in more complex queries - but slower for the simple case:

```
SELECT * FROM bigger_than_ones((SELECT array_agg(int_attribute) FROM my_table));
```

Related:

- [How to make an array from a SELECT returning more than one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896087/how-to-make-an-array-from-a-select-returning-more-than-one-row/9896739#9896739)

I assume you are aware of [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)? It could be used to radically simplify your test function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigger_than_ones(input_array int[])
  RETURNS SETOF int AS
$func$
   SELECT *
   FROM   unnest(input_array) elem
   WHERE  elem > 1;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Also, there is often a superior set-based approach to all of this. Constructing an array *from a set* just to pass it to a function may be unnecessary complication.

Comment: I didn't know about `unnest()` looks very useful, thanks. The reason I'm using a similarly structured function is because I need to calculate resulting merged time ranges (custom type) from multiple tables, in multiple places in my code. My best thought was to create a function that would do that, using as input all the time ranges, regardless of where I took it from, so I wouldn't have to make a more complex query each time. Sorry if something is not clear enough, english is not my first language.

Comment: @shevia: After your update the question is clear enough. Clearer than most, actually. The one big omission: your Postgres version - should be declared in *every* question. Just wanted to mention there *may* be a better approach. Maybe not. Maybe a custom aggregate function? Or `tstzrange(min(lower(...), max(upper(...))`. You might want to ask another question with the *exact* details of your setup and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution in another SO question: [Store select query's output in one array in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402043/store-select-querys-output-in-one-array-in-postgres)

I was able to use the array() operator as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM bigger_than_ones(ARRAY(SELECT int_attribute FROM my_table));
```

And got the expected output.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried creating a custom type? There are collection types such as arrays and tables and there are object types similar to single row records. You can then create a variable of this custom type to use as parameters.

Here's an example:

> CREATE Or REPLACE TYPE namearray AS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(10);

Comment: That is invalid for Postgres